# Capturing posessives and prefixes with Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex for Python to capture the various forms of "archipelago" that appear in a corpus.

Here is a test string:

`This is my sentence about islands, archipelagos, and archipelagic spaces. I want to make sure that the archipelago's cat is not forgotten. And we cannot forget the meta-archipelagic and protoarchipelagic historians, who tend to spell the plural 'archipelagoes.'`

I want to capture the following from the string:

```
archipelagos
archipelagic
archipelago's
meta-archipelagic
protoarchipelagic
archipelagoes
```

#### Attempt 1

Using the regex `(archipelag.*?)\b` and testing with [Pythex](http://pythex.org/?regex=(archipelag.*%3F)%5Cb&test_string=This%20is%20my%20sentence%20about%20islands%2C%20archipelagos%2C%20and%20archipelagic%20spaces.%20I%20want%20to%20make%20sure%20that%20the%20archipelago%27s%20cat%20is%20not%20forgotten.%20And%20we%20cannot%20forget%20the%20meta-archipelagic%20and%20protoarchipelagic%20historians%2C%20who%20tend%20to%20spell%20the%20plural%20%27archipelagoes.%27&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0), I capture portions of all six forms. But there are problems:

1. `archipelago's` is captured only as `archipelago`. I want to get the possessive.
2. `meta-archipelagic` is captured only as `archipelagic`. I want to be able to capture hyphenated prefixes.
3. `protoarchipelagic` is captured only as `archipelagic`. I want to be able to capture non-hyphenated prefixes.

#### Attempt 2

If I try the regex `(archipelag.*?)\s` (see [Pythex](http://pythex.org/?regex=(archipelag.*%3F)%5Cs&test_string=This%20is%20my%20sentence%20about%20islands%2C%20archipelagos%2C%20and%20archipelagic%20spaces.%20I%20want%20to%20make%20sure%20that%20the%20archipelago%27s%20cat%20is%20not%20forgotten.%20And%20we%20cannot%20forget%20the%20meta-archipelagic%20and%20protoarchipelagic%20historians%2C%20who%20tend%20to%20spell%20the%20plural%20%27archipelagoes.%27&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)), the possessive `archipelago's` is now captured, but the comma that follows the first instance is captured as well (e.g., `archipelagos,`). It fails to capture the final `'archipelagoes.'` altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `((?:\b\w+\b-)?\b\w*archipelag\w*\b(?:'s)?)` works for this.  If you have other requirements, you may want to modify it further.

Note the use of non-capturing groups `(?:)` to group expressions so that we can then match zero or one of them using `?`

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r"((?:\b\w+\b-)?\b\w*archipelag\w*\b(?:'s)?)")

corpus = "This is my sentence about islands, archipelagos, and archipelagic spaces. I want to make sure that the archipelago's cat is not forgotten. And we cannot forget the meta-archipelagic and protoarchipelagic historians, who tend to spell the plural 'archipelagoes.'"

for match in pat.findall(corpus):
    print(match)
```

prints

```
archipelagos
archipelagic
archipelago's
meta-archipelagic
protoarchipelagic
archipelagoes
```

[Here it is on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uuWmtA/1)

Answer (score 1):

Just make more concrete regex. This one could help:
`\b([a-zA-Z-]*archipelag[a-zA-Z']+)\b`

Explanation:

- `\b` assert position at a word boundary
- `[a-zA-Z-]*` matches zero or many from letters or `-`
- `[a-zA-Z-]+` matches one or many from letters or `'`

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/h6KVdE/1)

Answer (score 1):

Tried this one and it worked:

```
[a-zA-Z-]*arch[a-zA-Z']*
```

Comment: This works with the test string, but I think it would grab "architecture," "arches," and other such words.

My take on it is `([a-zA-Z-]*?archipel[a-zA-Z']*)`.

Comment: @BrianCroxall yes, it's true. `([a-zA-Z-]*?archipel[a-zA-Z']*)` would be a better answer.